# How to delete record from database in ASP.NET MVC without reloading the page?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

How can I delete data from my database in ASP.NET MVC without reloading the page ?

I tried all the methods but couldn't find a solution.

This is my ajax code :

```
(".remove-hasan").on("click", function () {

    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Main/DeleteFavourite" + id,
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: id, },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == "ok") {

                $(".modal-action-messages").empty();
                $(".modal-action-messages").append("Ürün Başarıyla Favorilerinizden Çıkarılmıştır.");

                $this.find(".remove").removeClass(".remove");
                $this.find(".remove").addClass(".remove");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DeleteFavourite(int id)
{
    var product = _uow.Favourite.GetAll()
                                .Where(p => p.ProductId == id)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
    _uow.Favourite.Delete(product);
        
    return Json("ok");
}
```

Comment: can you please add some examples what you tried. You can try jquery/ajax

Comment: @donstack hi added my codes.

Comment: url: "/Main/DeleteFavourite" + id, this part is wrong. Just put  url: "/Main/DeleteFavourite". Remove the Id

Comment: ok i removed but how i can delete without refresh page.

Comment: You haven't shown us anything that would cause the page to be reloaded!

Comment: @phuzi When I delete the favorite data, it is deleted when I refresh the page from the favorite page. I want it to delete directly without refreshing the page when it deletes.

Comment: No, it's deleted when you the AJAX POST is triggered. Are you trying to remove the record from the page once it has been successfully deleted?

Comment: @phuzi Yes, after the record is deleted from the database, I want it also deleted from the page

Comment: We're going to need to see your HTML that you're attempting to update (remove)

Comment: @phuzi https://pastebin.com/hTmR8P4R Here.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include relevant HTML/JavaScript (not just everything)

Comment: tr class="tbody-item">
<td class="product-remove">
<div class="remove remove-hasan" id="favorite-remove" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#action-WishlistModal" data-id="@item.Id">×</div>

Comment: I can't edit question. There are my remove html code. @phuzi

Comment: You should be able to edit your own question!

Comment: @phuzi I can't edit my question its says "you can't edit because too much code has been added"

Comment: Here is my html code : tr class="tbody-item">
           <td class="product-remove">
            <div class="remove remove-hasan" id="favorite-remove" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#action-WishlistModal" data-id="@item.Id">×</div>

Comment: You should only add enough to highlight the issue.

Comment: Failing that try adding a new question and potentially remove this one.

Answer (score 1):

So, your major problem is how to remove the entry from frontend i.e. HTML page.

Once you get the success from ajax call, you need to find that row from HTML table and simply delete it.

Assuming, you code is already reaching inside

> response == "ok"

It's always suggested to use Id for each row, which I think you already have.

```
success: function (response) {
            if (response == "ok") {

            $('[data-id='+id+']').remove();
            }
}
```

Here data-id is used inside jQuery selector to uniquely find that row.

Comment: @hasan dont forget to accept the answer as it help other people having similar question/issue

Answer (score 0):

As I see your HTML file. You can do it in the following way.

**Steps**

1. In the `success` function. find the closest `tr` and then call jQuery function `remove()`

```
$(".remove-hasan").on("click", function () {
    var delButton = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Main/DeleteFavourite" + id,
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: id, },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == "ok") {
            //Your code        
            ...
            delButton.closest("tr").remove();
        }
    });
});
```